# How to write this Fulfillment codes(including output)?

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, dialogflow-es

First of all, I tried to write how to save users input data to google sheet after developing the simple codes. It'**s able to work**. Thank Mr.Master for providing this tutorial(Below **the link**).

Reference Mr.Master: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huwUpJZsTok

Next, I bumped into the problem below the code. I didn't know how to write it in Fulfillment. Could someone realize it to teach me?

Tool: Dialogflow, Google sheet, Firebase.

Theme: Order process

I tried to write **Forhere()** there. However, it didn't work.(**First** code)

```
function Forhere(agent){
    const{
      forhere, howmanypeople, whattime, namelist
    } = agent.parameters;
    const data1 = [{
      Forhere: forhere,
      HowManyPeople: howmanypeople,
      Time: whattime,
      Name: namelist
    }];
    axios.post('......', data1);
  }





{/*....This code is a result of test(second one)
  "responseId": "d0f44937-e58a-4b71-b6dc-ec2d6c39337b-f308a5c4",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "黃大哥",
    "parameters": {
      "forhere": [
        "內用"
      ],
      "howmanypeople": [
        2
      ],
      "whattime": [
        **{
          "date_time": "2019-09-19T14:00:00+08:00"
        }**
      ],
      "namelist": [
        "黃大哥"
      ]
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/test-tyrpxs/agent/sessions/5dd26d5c-bd99-072c-3693-41f95a3a348d/contexts/forhere",
        "lifespanCount": 4,
        "parameters": {
          "howmanypeople": [
            2
          ],
          "namelist.original": [
            "黃大哥"
          ],
          "howmanypeople.original": [
            "2"
          ],
          "forhere": [
            "內用"
          ],
          "whattime.original": [
            "明天下午2點"
          ],
          "welcome": "嗨",
          "whattime": [
            {
              "date_time": "2019-09-19T14:00:00+08:00"
            }
          ],
          "namelist": [
            "黃大哥"
          ],
          "welcome.original": "hi",
          "forhere.original": [
            "內用"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/test-tyrpxs/agent/intents/ec0f55c4-e9c9-401f-bce7-d2478c40fb85",
      "displayName": "ForHere"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 4992
    },
    "languageCode": "zh-tw"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 4,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout."
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank Mr.Rubén for helping me to do a typesetting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
let forhere= agent.parameters.forhere;
let howmanypeople= agent.parameters.howmanypeople;
let whattime= agent.parameters.whattime;
let namelist= agent.parameters.namelist;
```

then use this variables in your api call.

Comment: First, I'm very grateful for your help. But, is it similar to this code I wrote, isn't it?                         
const{
      forhere, howmanypeople, whattime, namelist
    } = agent.parameters;
    const data1 = [{
      Forhere:forhere,
      HowManyPeople:howmanypeople,
      Time:whattime,
      Name:namelist
    }];

Comment: Okay got you, first of all if you have a trial account with Firebase it will not allow you to call external Api from Fulfillment.And if you have upgraded your plan , then on the fulfillment window click on "View Execution logs in Firebase console" -> then tell me the what the log says after intent is called.

Answer (score 0):

To T.Ali:

Dialogflowfirebasefulfillment&Error message:

Although I think this error didn't show where these mistakes are.

```
Dialogflow Request body: {"responseId":"ab277bc6-3bcc-4c4b-9a94-192b9ecfb8af-f308a5c4","queryResult":{"queryText":"黃大哥","parameters":{"forhere":"內用","whattime":{"date_time":"2019-09-20T12:00:00+08:00"},"howmanypeople":3,"namelist":"黃大哥"},"allRequiredParamsPresent":true,"outputContexts":[{"name":"projects/test-tyrpxs/agent/sessions/5dd26d5c-bd99-072c-3693-41f95a3a348d/contexts/forhere","lifespanCount":4,"parameters":{"welcome":"嗨","welcome.original":"hi","forhere":"內用","forhere.original":"內用","whattime":{"date_time":"2019-09-20T12:00:00+08:00"},"whattime.original":"明天中午","howmanypeople":3,"howmanypeople.original":"3","namelist":"黃大哥","namelist.original":"黃大哥"}}],"intent":{"name":"projects/test-tyrpxs/agent/intents/ec0f55c4-e9c9-401f-bce7-d2478c40fb85","displayName":"ForHere"},"intentDetectionConfidence":1,"languageCode":"zh-tw"},"originalDetectIntentRequest":{"payload":{}},"session":"projects/test-tyrpxs/agent/sessions/5dd26d5c-bd99-072c-3693-41f95a3a348d"}

Error: No handler for requested intent
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:317:29)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:105:9)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Furthermore, I've write below the code worked formally(input users data to google sheet).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gey6L.png)